# Solution for "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error

I am developing an app for measuring the signal strength. I have no errors in code, but when I run the app I get an error saying that "The application (app name) package name has stopped unexpectedly". Herewith I am attaching the xml file, java file and android manifest file. Kindly reply as soon as possible.

**XML FILE**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
   >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ref"
        android:textSize="30sp"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bfind"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="@string/ref1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


                                <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/signalLevel" />
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/signalLevelInfo"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA FILE**

```
package com.signalstrength.gsmece;


import android.os.Bundle;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button find;
TelephonyManager _telephonyManager;
GsmSignalStrengthListener _signalStrengthListener;

TextView display;
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
String IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
int lac = location.getLac();
int cid = location .getCid();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
_signalStrengthListener = new GsmSignalStrengthListener();

        find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bfind);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1) ;

     find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            display.setText("Calculating....");




                    }

    });
    }
    public abstract class CellSignalStrength extends Object
    {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.signalstrength.gsmece"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.signalatrength.gsmece.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>     
       </application>

</manifest>
```

**LOGCAT FILE**

```
03-16 19:15:16.859: D/AndroidRuntime(277): Shutting down VM

03-16 19:15:16.859: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.signalstrength.gsmece/com.signalstrength.gsmece.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.signalstrength.gsmece.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)

03-16 19:15:17.089: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 11 more

03-16 19:15:25.850: I/Process(277): Sending signal. PID: 277 SIG: 9

03-16 19:15:50.780: D/AndroidRuntime(288): Shutting down VM

03-16 19:15:50.780: W/dalvikvm(288): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.signalstrength.gsmece/com.signalstrength.gsmece.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at com.signalstrength.gsmece.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)

03-16 19:15:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  ... 11 more

03-16 19:20:50.879: I/Process(288): Sending signal. PID: 288 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest file has wrong package name when starting the main activity. Replace

```
android:name="com.signalatrength.gsmece.MainActivity"
```

with

```
android:name="com.signalstrength.gsmece.MainActivity"
```

Comment: Hi Vaibhav. I have rectified it, but even now I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call getSystemServices until onCreate is called.  Move the lines where you get a TelephonyManager and those that rely on it into onCreate